# What is the most efficient technique to render a sequence with 80% non animated images?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, video

I have a VSE with 100 images. Every 5th image will have a Fade-In transition. Every 5th image is 2 seconds long while the others are only 1 second long.

If there were no fade effect, I could have rendered at 1fps. Since there is fade effect I need to render at 24FPS. Right now, I am rendering entirely at 24fps making it time consuming.

Is there a more efficient way (faster) to render this setup.

Basically, my query is can Blender skip rendering of intermediate frames and simply show the first frame until a new image is encountered.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: You say you have images loaded into the VSE, so you've already rendered all these images.  Are you talking about render time rendering your VSE timeline to .mp4?  I mean that is basically what it's doing, processing each frame and doing compression to give you the smallest file possible while maintaining quality.

Comment: @AllenSimpson yes, I am referring to the render time rendering to .mp4. If I decide to go without any fade effect, I am left with 100 images each image 1 second long. Now, I could generate .mp4 video blazingly fast by setting FPS to 1. Since I have fade effect every 5th frame, I will have to  render that image at 24fps. Right now, I am rendering every single image including those without any effect at 24FPS, leading to too much delay. If I could set every 5th image to be rendered at 24FPS and all other at 1FPS I could save a lot of processing time. Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think Blender has any options for variable frame rate, but maybe someone else knows.  In general Blender renders video slower than other applications, but I can't speak to quality or filesize.

Comment: @AllenSimpson thanks